# a null object reference error on listner in Recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created an adapter for my recycler view.and created an interface with delete function but nothing happens when I run the app and from debugging I came to know that the listener is null.I have defined the interface functions in another class file.
I don't have any idea what's going on. can anyone help out?

Adapter:

```
    public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<NotificationItem> mNotificationList;
    private onItemClickListner mListner;

    private Context myContext;
    private int layoutResID;

   public interface onItemClickListner{
     void onItemClick(int position);
     void onDeleteClick(int position);
    }

//    public void setOnItemClickListner(onItemClickListner listner){
//       mListner=listner;
//    }

    //NOTIFICATION HOLDER
    public static class NotificationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView mNotificationTextView;
        public RelativeLayout mNotificaionHolderLayout;
        public ImageView imageDelete;
        onItemClickListner listner;


        public NotificationViewHolder(View itemView,final onItemClickListner listner) {
            super(itemView);
            mNotificationTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.NotificationTextView);
            mNotificaionHolderLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification__item_container);
            imageDelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_delete_image);
            this.listner=listner;


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   if (listner!=null){
                       int position=getAdapterPosition();
                       if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                           listner.onItemClick(position);
                       }
                   }
                }
            });

            imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listner!=null){
                        int position=getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listner.onDeleteClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }//NOTIFICATION HOLDER

    public NotificationAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NotificationItem> notificationList,onItemClickListner listner){
        myContext=context;
        this.layoutResID=resource;
        mNotificationList=notificationList;
        this.mListner=listner;
    }


    @Override
    public NotificationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_notificationitem,parent,false);
        NotificationViewHolder evh=new NotificationViewHolder(v,mListner);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NotificationItem currentItem=mNotificationList.get(position);
        holder.mNotificaionHolderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Getcolor(position)));
        holder.mNotificationTextView.setText(currentItem.getNotifi_Name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotificationList.size();
    }

    private String Getcolor(int position)
    {
        String clr;

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                clr="#FF9966";
                break;

            case 1:
                clr="#009900";
                break;

            case 2:
                clr="#006699";
                break;

            case 3:
                clr="#751947";
                break;
            case 4:
                clr="#FF9966";
                break;

            case 5:
                clr="#009900";
                break;

            case 6:
                clr="#006699";
                break;

            case 7:
                clr="#751947";
                break;


            default:
                clr="#FFA500";
                break;
        }
        return clr;
    }

}
```

LayoutFile:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/notification__item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NotificationTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="320dp"
        android:minWidth="320dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notification_delete_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/close1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> this is from my home activity class where I initialized the listener,

```
  @Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    FlashMessage("Clicked");

}

@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
       FlashMessage("DELETED ON POSITION : " +position);
       System.out.print("onDeleteClick");
       listNotifi.remove(position);
       nfAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

}
```

> Adapter in-home activity

```
  NotificationAdapter nfAdapter=new NotificationAdapter(Home.this,R.layout.listview_notification_item, listNotifi,this);
            lvNotification.setAdapter(nfAdapter);
```

Comment: show your activity code and post your logcat

Comment: You wrote that your listener is `null`. Then you forgot to call method `setOnClickListener` of `NotificationAdapter` from your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Comment: I have an image view with delete icon. I called setOnClickListener on that,

Comment: That is different listener. Read about callback. Check my below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not implementing the listener in your activity or fragment you have to implement your method.

```
  public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<NotificationItem> mNotificationList;
private onItemClickListner mListner;

private Context myContext;
private int layoutResID;
String eduflexURL="https://eduflex.co.in/portal/";

public interface onItemClickListner{
 void onItemClick(int position);
 void onDeleteClick(int position);
}
//remove this no need
//public void setOnItemClickListner(onItemClickListner listner){
  // mListner=listner;
 // }

//NOTIFICATION HOLDER
public static class NotificationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mNotificationTextView;
    public RelativeLayout mNotificaionHolderLayout;
    public ImageView imageDelete;
    onItemClickListner listner;


    public NotificationViewHolder(View itemView,final onItemClickListner listner) {
        super(itemView);
        mNotificationTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.NotificationTextView);
        mNotificaionHolderLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification__item_container);
        imageDelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_delete_image);
        this.listner=listner;


        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if (listner!=null){
                   int position=getAdapterPosition();
                   if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                       mListner.onItemClick(position);
                   }
               }
            }
        });

        imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listner!=null){
                    int position=getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        mListner.onDeleteClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}//NOTIFICATION HOLDER
```

//Here add your Interface in Your Constructor

```
 public NotificationAdapter(Context context, int resource, 
    ArrayList<NotificationItem> 
 notificationList,onItemClickListner mListener){
    myContext=context;
    this.layoutResID=resource;
    mNotificationList=notificationList;
    this.mListener = mListener
}


@Override
public NotificationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_notificationitem,parent,false);
    NotificationViewHolder evh=new NotificationViewHolder(v,mListner);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NotificationItem currentItem=mNotificationList.get(position);
    holder.mNotificaionHolderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Getcolor(position)));
    holder.mNotificationTextView.setText(currentItem.getNotifi_Name());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNotificationList.size();
}

private String Getcolor(int position)
{
    String clr;

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            clr="#FF9966";
            break;

        case 1:
            clr="#009900";
            break;

        case 2:
            clr="#006699";
            break;

        case 3:
            clr="#751947";
            break;
        case 4:
            clr="#FF9966";
            break;

        case 5:
            clr="#009900";
            break;

        case 6:
            clr="#006699";
            break;

        case 7:
            clr="#751947";
            break;


        default:
            clr="#FFA500";
            break;
    }
    return clr;
}
```

}

In Your Activity or Fragment Implement It

```
   public class yourActivity extends Activity implements 
                  NotificationAdapter.onItemClickListner{


       //Add the Override method


   }
```

When you call your Adapter

```
  NotificationAdapter madapter = new 

  NotificationAdapter(YourActivity.this,resId,list,this)
```

Comment: Happy to help 

Comment: I have checked with a FlashMessage, and the ondeleteClick method is working fine.Although.There is another issue. I am getting the items from an XML file and all the items are binding perfectly. But see I have written a switch case to change the background color for a different position.8 colors.even though after the fourth item color begins from the beginning. And removing the item from the ArrayList is not removing my item from the recycler view. Showing error index out of bound. says size is 4.but I haven't declared size as 4 anywhere.

Comment: and .remove(position) is not removing the item

Comment: repeating colors where a stupid mistake.resolved. And from what I am seeing now if I selected the first item on the recycle view the last item is removed.and it won't show that it's removed.it will show only after its reopened

Answer (score 0):

```
In your code :
if (listner==null){
                    int position=getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listner.onDeleteClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }

Why you are checking for null and in fact You need to check if (listner!=null){}
```

Comment: but you have posted the code, where listener ==null, can you post your updated code

Answer (score 0):

Put below code inside your `Activity` or `Fragment` after you initialized the notificationAdapter.

```
notificationAdapter.setOnClickListener(new NotificationAdapter.onItemClickListner(){

    void onItemClick(int position){

    }
    void onDeleteClick(int position){

    }
});
```

Comment: yes, it worked for me. I have solved the issue with another solution above. by implementing the adapter and overriding the methods. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to call **setOnItemClickListner** or you have to pass listner object in 
**NotificationAdapter** constructor and assign to the mListner

for Example

```
NotificationAdapter adapter=new NotificationAdapter(context,res,list,"Pass your listerner here");
```

in Adapter

```
 public NotificationAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NotificationItem> notificationList,onItemClickListner listener){
        myContext=context;
        this.layoutResID=resource;
        mNotificationList=notificationList;
this.mListner=listener;
    }
```